# How to create textbox in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I wanted to create text box inside the canvas.

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="50"></canvas>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var input = new CanvasInput({
canvas: document.getElementById('canvas')
});
```

when I run the file HTML not have anything.

Comment: you are not inserting any textbox inside the canvas? this is your Complete code?

Comment: I'm put like this >> http://goldfirestudios.com/blog/108/CanvasInput-HTML5-Canvas-Text-Input

Comment: i post the answer check it it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just simply missed the libraries ***CanvasInput.min.js*** simply download from the [***here***](https://github.com/goldfire/CanvasInput) and add to your code.

**Sample Code:**

```
<html>
  <title>sample</title>
  <head> 
    <script src="CanvasInput.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="50"></canvas>
    <script>
        var input = new CanvasInput({
                     canvas: document.getElementById('canvas')
         });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot simply render a standard HTML input field inside a canvas, if that's what you wanted to achieve.

It looks like you were trying to utilize code from [this developer page](http://goldfirestudios.com/blog/108/CanvasInput-HTML5-Canvas-Text-Input). But it seems you overlooked that there is a whole lot more Javascript required to simulate an input field as a canvas graphic element. Check out [this Git repository](https://github.com/goldfire/CanvasInput) to see the whole code.

I made a [CodePen showing how to put a text input inside a canvas](http://codepen.io/schafeld/pen/aZbBJQ) with this technique. For a quick demo add this script tag to your HTML code (you may want to host the code yourself later):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://goldfirestudios.com/proj/canvasinput/CanvasInput.min.js?v=1.2.0"></script>
```